# .net example of using client certificates in web service call?

Tags: c#, web-services, ssl, asmx, certificate

I'd like to use client certificates to verify the identity of administrative callers to my web service. Then I can issue certificates only to the people I want to call my web service and be pretty sure noone else can call it. This is in a very controlled scenario where only one or two people will get the client certificate, so distribution isn't a hard problem.

[This article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/901183) provides a good example of how to call a web service using a client certificate.

But how can I check details of the client certificate from within my web service? [This old article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649247.aspx) talks about configuring IIS to do it, but I'd like to do it programmatically within my app. I think?

thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Do you mean WCF clients and services, or are you referring to legacy ASMX web services?

Comment: I mean asmx web services

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The incoming Request has a ClientCertificates collection that you can interrogate -- you can check the various fields in the cert or check the actual raw byte data (perhaps against a datastore or other source) if you want to completely validate it.

Note, if you issue the certs from your own private CA, you will need to install the CA's cert on your webserver into a store that is visible to all users, otherwise IIS won't request those certs from the user (due to the nature of how the server/client interaction works.)